# how do you do linux patching in enterprise environment?

Tags: patch-management

what are the most common tool that you used for linux patching in enterprise environment?

Comment: What Linux flavor? Some vendors have their own "enterprise patching solution" that they endorse (sell) & support

Comment: Hi Voretaq7,

Possible to give me Red Hat , SLES and Solaris? or one that you have experience before

Answer (score 1):

We use yum, against local repositories maintained with [mrepo](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/mrepo/).  Those repos include, among others, RHEL updates from RHN, and the [VMware Tools OS Specific packages](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/general/tools-os-pkg).

Answer (score 1):

[Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) or similar is a common solution -- This is a bit more than just "patching", but in large environments configuration/deployment management tools bring other benefits that you'll want too :)

Answer (score 0):

`rpm`, `make`, and `ssh`.

Comment: Never took you for a masochist Warner! :)

Comment: Yea, probably would have been better not to answer an ambiguous question that has already been answered repeatedly.  =)  We need to kick up the moderation here for a little while.  http://serverfault.com/questions/123144/managing-an-application-across-multiple-servers-or-pxe-vs-cfengine-chef-puppet/123153#123153

Comment: Hi Warner, again I am not spamming.

Comment: Hi Voretaq7,
Thanks for your reply above.

Answer (score 0):

We're a SLES office here. Because of that, Novell's SMT (Subscription Management Tool) works exceedingly well for us. When setting up new servers we register against our SMT server and it handles all of the registration and repo setup. We'll still have to set an update policy for each server, but it works well.

Which is to say, voretaq7 nailed it in the comment on your post. It depends on what Linux you're using.

Comment: I will take note of your explanation, really good for my knowledge. Thanks.